# Getting "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" when trying to implement search feature on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a dropdown search by category feature on my webapp. I am currently trying to get the dropdown menu to work, but I am constantly getting the error saying:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

Here is the view:

```
<%= form_for @search, html: {class: "pure-form"} do |s| %>
 <div class="field">
    <%= s.label :category %>
    <%= s.select(:category, options_for_select([['Other', 'Other'], ["Breakfast", "Breakfast"], ["Lunch/Dinner", "Lunch/Dinner"], ["Dessert", "Dessert"]])) %>
<%end%>

<div class="card-columns">
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body p-1">
                <%= image_tag image.image, class: 'd-block w-100' %>
                <%= link_to image.title, image_path(image.id), class: "btn btn-primary stretched-link" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
    def new 
        @search = Search.new
        @categories = Image.uniq.pluck(:category)
    end

    def create
        @search = Search.create(search_params)
        redirect_to @search
    end

    def show 
        @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    end 

    private
    
    def search_params 
        params.require(:search).permit(:category)
    end
        
end
```

And here are the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'pages#home'

  get '/images', controller: 'images', action: 'recent'

  get '/upload', controller: 'images', action: 'new'

  get '/@:username', to: 'users#show', as: :profile

  delete 'images/:id(.:format)', :to => 'images#destroy'

  resources :images, only: [:index, :show, :create]
  get  'searches/search'

  resources :searches
end
```

I tried to configure different things to see if I could get it working, but I could not. I am very unclear as to what is the problem. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the URL where you're seeing that error?

Comment: The URL's are: http://localhost:3000/images and http://localhost:3000/@[Username]

Comment: I don't think either of those would hit the `SearchesController` that you've included above.  Assuming the view code above is in `app/views/searches/new.html.erb`, I'd expect visiting /searches/new to show that view correctly - does that work?  Believe the /images and /@username URLs would hit the `ImagesController` and `UsersController` and their corresponding views respectively.